# Display CustomizableUI widget of type "custom" as icon in Firefox customization palette

Tags: firefox-addon-sdk, xul

I develop a restartless Firefox addon using a [`CustomizableUI`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/JavaScript_code_modules/CustomizableUI.jsm) widget of the type *custom*. The widget itself contains several `XUL` elements.

Currently, the full widget appears in the `customization-palette-container` when customizing the Firefox toolbar. I would prefer to display an icon instead. What is the best approach to customize the appearance of the `toolbarpaletteitem`?

I am aware of the examples which use the `nsIStyleSheetService` ([Jorge Villalobos' Australis Hello Button](https://blog.mozilla.org/addons/2014/03/06/australis-for-add-on-developers-2/), the "Comprehensive Example" outlined in the `CustomizableUI` docs). However, both examples only work for widgets of the default type *button*.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using pretty weird approach but it works. Here is an excerpt:

```
/**
 * Handle the add-on being activated on install/enable.
 * 
 * @param {Object} aData: Add-on's data.
 * @param {Number} aReason: Reason why method is runned.
 */
function startup(aData, aReason) AddonManager.getAddonByID(aData.id, function(addon) {
    // Initialize stringbundles
    getString.init(addon);

    // Create new toolbar button
    CustomizableUI.createWidget({
        id: "tagssidebar-toolbarbutton",
        defaultArea: CustomizableUI.AREA_NAVBAR,
        label: getString("command.label"),
        tooltiptext: getString("command.tooltip"),
        type: "button", 
        /**
         * @todo When disabling/enabling add-on these elements may already exist!
         */
        onBeforeCreated: function(aDocument) {
            // We need to add more UI than the toolbarbutton (broadcaster, key and menuitem):
            let XUL_NS = "http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul";
            // Broadcaster
            let broadcasterset = aDocument.getElementById("mainBroadcasterSet");
            if (broadcasterset) {
                let broadcaster = aDocument.createElementNS(XUL_NS, "broadcaster");
                broadcaster.setAttribute("autoCheck", "false");
                broadcaster.setAttribute("group", "sidebar");
                broadcaster.setAttribute("id", "viewSidebar_tagssidebar");
                broadcaster.setAttribute("oncommand", "toggleSidebar('viewSidebar_tagssidebar');");
                broadcaster.setAttribute("sidebarurl", "chrome://tagssidebar/content/sidebar.xul");
                broadcaster.setAttribute("sidebartitle", getString("command.label"));
                broadcaster.setAttribute("type", "checkbox");
                broadcasterset.appendChild(broadcaster);
            }
            // Key
            let keyset = aDocument.getElementById("mainKeyset");
            if (keyset) {
                let key = aDocument.createElementNS(XUL_NS, "key");
                key.setAttribute("command", "viewSidebar_tagssidebar");
                key.setAttribute("id", "key_openSidebar_tagssidebar");
                key.setAttribute("key", getString("command.key"));
                key.setAttribute("modifiers", getString("command.modifiers"));
                keyset.appendChild(key);
            }
            // Menuitem
            let menupopup = aDocument.getElementById("viewSidebarMenu");
            if (menupopup) {
                let menuitem = aDocument.createElementNS(XUL_NS, "menuitem");
                menuitem.setAttribute("class", "menuitem-iconic tagssidebar-icon16");
                menuitem.setAttribute("key", "key_openSidebar_tagssidebar");
                menuitem.setAttribute("label", getString("command.label"));
                menuitem.setAttribute("observes", "viewSidebar_tagssidebar");
                menuitem.setAttribute("tooltiptext", getString("command.tooltip"));
                menupopup.appendChild(menuitem);
            }
        },
        onCreated: function(aNode) {
            // Add ID of broadcaster we created before as a command:
            aNode.setAttribute("command", "viewSidebar_tagssidebar");
            return aNode;
        }
    });

    // Load stylesheet
    gStylestheetSrv = CC["@mozilla.org/content/style-sheet-service;1"].getService(CI.nsIStyleSheetService);
    gStylesURI = Services.io.newURI("chrome://tagssidebar/skin/overlay.css", null, null);
    gStylestheetSrv.loadAndRegisterSheet(gStylesURI, gStylestheetSrv.USER_SHEET);
}); // end startup(aData, aReason)
```

You can see the full code here: https://bitbucket.org/ondrejd/tagssidebar/src/c0ae929b5a1623f791f8486d5815a087dfced25f/src/bootstrap.js?at=default

Comment: Thanks for sharing your workaround. I came to the conclusion that there is no official solution to this problem ...